# HTML/CSS: shrink a cell and its content

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table where one row is especially wide.

```
<table border=1>
 <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb1234567890bbb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>
</table>
```

I like to CUT the content of the long cell by CSS of td. I do not want to cut the content.

Setting max-width of the desired cell shrinks the cell but not the content. So the content overlaps the cell.

```
<table border=1>
 <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>aaa</td><td style="max-width: 30px;">bbb1234567890bbb</td></tr>
 <tr><td>aaa</td><td>bbb</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want a shrinked cell and no overlapping (and also no word-wrapping).

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I don't get it.  The cell automatically sizes to the content, there is no extra space in the cell already.

Comment: use width instead of max-width and give with in '%'

Comment: The cell takes up the exact space it needs to to show the content without wrapping, how do you want this differently? https://jsfiddle.net/31kcruam/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. But I think that overflow: hidden along with text-overflow: ellipsis might solve your problem.

```
  td {
      max-width:100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Gti1qhErZlTMjr8m7sIG?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what is the result you want to achieve, you can use

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

or

```
text-overflow: clip;
```

so that the content will not overlap the cell.

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the overflow property on your `td`.  You haven't said what you want to do with the overflow so I have shown three options:

- overflow scroll
- overflow hidden
- overflow hidden by ellipsis

```css
td {
  max-width: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.with-overflow {
  overflow: auto;  /* adds scollbars if needed */
}

.without-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;  /* just hides any overflow */
}

.with-ellipsis {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;   /* just hides any overflow and appends ... to the end of the string */
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td class="with-overflow">adds scroll bars</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td class="without-overflow">without overflow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td class="with-ellipsis">with ellispsis</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[More information about overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

[More information about text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)